# How to return only the first error for each field in a Laravel Validator?

Tags: php, laravel

When getting errors back for a simple validation of a set of fields, Laravel returns a key/value with "field" / Array with a string inside,  instead of a simple string with the description of the errors.

This is what the validator looks code looks like:

```
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
            'email'=>'required|email|unique:user',
            'first_name'=>'required|min:3',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails())
        {
            $response = ['errors'=>$validator->errors()];
            return $this->r(ResponseFactory::invalid_input_params($response));
        }
```

This is what I get returned:

```
{
    "code": 400,
    "kind": "invalid_input_params",
    "status": "error",
    "data": {
        "errors": {
            "email": [
                "The email has already been taken."
            ],
            "first_name": [
                "The first name field is required."
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I intend to have:

```
{
    "code": 400,
    "kind": "invalid_input_params",
    "status": "error",
    "data": {
        "errors": {
            "email": "The email has already been taken.",
            "first_name": "The first name field is required."
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to feed a frontend app with errors from an API endpoint, for a usual form, and want only to have an error per field.

Per default Laravel outputs an array for each field, even if there's just an error per field - I'm trying to convert it into a string and take only the first error.

Comment: Try `$validator->errors()->first()`. Did this quite long back, not sure if it still follows the same syntax.

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea. With your approach, you then have to have multiple versions of the code which reads and parses this data. Because at some point, you will end up with more than one validation error on a specific field. Right now you may not have, but you can't assume it will stay like that in the future. Applications always evolve and increase in scope. If there's only one item in the error array for each field, why is that a problem? Just loop through them. If you only happen to loop once, so what?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the version comment you posted @ADyson - on a specific field you would just want to normally show an error to the user, the first, most pressing one, on UX terms, for a simple app - I think its a reasonable

Comment: @nice_dev this will just output the first error, for just one field, which is not the desired functionality

Comment: Why not show them all the errors at once for each field? Why should they have to submit the form several times to see all the problems that are occurring on one field? That is a not a good user experience, in my opinion - it could be very frustrating. But that's just my point of view...you are welcome to disagree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`errors()` return a [`MessageBag`](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Support/MessageBag.html) instance on which you can use the `keys()` method to retrieve the messages for each key in a loop.

```
<?php

$errors = [];
$messageBag = $validator->errors();

foreach($messageBag->keys() as $fieldKey){
  $errors[ $fieldKey ] = $messageBag->first($fieldKey);
}

$response = ['errors' => $errors];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't notice that the errors were displayed flat , with the dot notation  and not with nested arrays, which is a case I need to handle - this way, this answer makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

add this code to your form request
`protected $stopOnFirstFailure = true;`

```
<?php

class MyFormRequest extends FormRequest {

   protected $stopOnFirstFailure = true;

}
```